# ASP.NET Development Server - Empty webResource.axd after conversion from 2.0 to 3.5

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I have moved a project from asp.net 2.0 to 3.5. The original project was using the atlas ajax extensions so I have modified the code to use the built in ajax features in 3.5.

When running the project within the dev environemnt (VS2008 on Vista Business SP1) and using the asp.net dev server I receive javascript errors such as **WebForm_PostBackOptions** which point to a missing handler/module.

If I deploy the project and run it stand alone within IIS or if I use Fiddler2 while running in VS2008 I do not see the errors and fiddler shows that the axd files are being downloaded correctly. Also deploying to a 2003 server does not show any issues.

I could just carry on and forget this as it works when deployed but I would like to understand what is happening. Has anyone got an ideas as to what is going on here and how to get the same results accross all environments?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get these same errors when you run in VS2008 but with IIS instead of the dev server?